# sequential search using linked list without duplicate keys

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to do a seq search, check for duplicate key, if present, I only need to update the value. But when I try to do it using linked list, I'm getting memory issues.

Normal code to put the values without having to check for duplicate keys(commented out in the code) works fine.

```
class seqSearch
{
public:
    int N;

    //helper class node
    class node
    {
    public:
        char key;
        int val;
        node *next;

        node(){ key = NULL; val = NULL; next = NULL;}
        node(char k,int v, node *nxt)
        {
            this->key = k;
            this->val = v;
            this->next = nxt;
        }

    };

    node *first;
    seqSearch(){N=0;}
    bool isEmpty(){return first == NULL;}
    int size(){return N;}
    void put(char,int);
    int get(char);
};

void seqSearch::put(char k, int v)
{
    /*
    node *oldfirst = first;
    //first = new node(k,v,oldfirst);
    first = new node;
    first->key = k;
    first->val = v;
    first->next = oldfirst;
    N++;
    */

    for (node *x = first; x!= NULL; x=x->next)
    {
        //node *oldfirst = first;
        //first = new node(k, v, oldfirst);
        if(x->key == k)
        {
            x->val = v; 
            return;
        }
    }
    first = new node(k, v, first); N++;

}
```

Comment: Define "memory issues"

Comment: what errors are you getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`first` should be initialized with `NULL` in constructor

Comment: Thanks. It worked fine. I had initiated every element inside node class to NULL in constructor, but not the object first as such. Once I did that, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems.

1. You always reset `first` when you make a new node.
2. You set `first` node's `next` equal to itself, guaranteeing you can't walk your list.

Try something more like this:

```
void seqSearch::put(char k, int v)
{
    node* last = NULL;
    node* current = NULL;

    for (node *x = first; x!= NULL; x=x->next)
    {
        if(x->key == k)
        {
            x->val = v; 
            return;
        }
        last = x;
    }
    current = new node(k, v, NULL); N++;
    if( last == NULL )
        first = current;
    else
        last->next = current;
}
```

This:

1. Tracks the newly created node as current.
2. Tracks the last node traversed, so it can have its `next` set to the newly created node.
3. Sets `first` to current node if there wasn't a last node (ie, we didn't traverse any nodes).

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I have issues with the snippet: 

current = new node(k, v, NULL); N++;
    if( last == NULL )
        first = current;

it says current undefined. I do not understand how though.